# Controlling row height due to long Choice fields

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view

I have a list of contractors I am putting together. One of my fields is a Choice field I'm using to show all of the services offered. Some will have 20+ services assigned, and when these are all selected, the row is very large. I have 200+ contractors so this won't work.

When I edit in grid view, it let's me limit the row height, which is perfect. But I would prefer the list view that I share out to my partners limit the row height so it's easier for them to navigate.

I've seen a few coding options, but they all seem to be CSS and my list tells me to enter JSON code.

Any help? Anywhere I can find someone to code for me?

Help :(

Answer (score 0):

To specify the row height, you need to format the choice column and add the property "height" in your json code.

[image]

```
{
      "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
      "elmType": "div",
      "txtContent": "@currentField",
      "style": {
        "width": "500px",
        "height": "100px"
      }
    }
```

Before and After:

[image]